# Hive Bring Table to Local Driver for Fast Debugging on CLI

Tags: sql, hive

I have a large Hive table on HDFS. Every time I query it, it runs a map reduce job which is slow.

For debugging my code on CLI, I want a fast query. Is it possible to sample rows of the table and bring them to the local machine. Then the hive queries would only run on the local machine without map reduce. If yes, how?

PS I know that map reduce runs for some commands only. I have nested structs which trigger map reduce.